# Force log out if multiple sign-in's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-user

How do I configure Devise so that if a user signs in from another device (not Devise!) and has failed to log out from that other device such that the user is asked if a forced log out of the OTHER log-in should be done?

I assume Devise can detect that a new session is about to be created.  Is my assumption correct?

Basically, I need only a single user signed in to be using my application at any one time.  Is this possible to do?  That is, if I have two valid users x1@xyz.com and x2@abc.com, the two users can both be signed in at the same time but x1@xyz.com and x2@abc.com can each be only signed in once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem: https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension

specifically the :session_limitable module